# The type ResultSetExtractor is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <List<Employee>>

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I am learning spring. while creating one example i got error.

```
The type ResultSetExtractor is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <List<Employee>>
```

I implement the app as below

**Employee.java**

```
package com.develop;
public class Employee {
    private int id;  
    private String name;  
    private float salary;   
    public Employee(){} 
    public Employee(int id, String name, float salary){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public float getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(float salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    } 

}
```

**EmployeeDao.java**

```
package com.develop;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor;

public class EmployeeDao {
private JdbcTemplate template;

public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate template) {
    this.template = template;
}

public List<Employee> getAllEmployees(){  
     return template.query("select * from employee",new ResultSetExtractor<List<Employee>>(){  
        @Override  
         public List<Employee> extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException,  
                DataAccessException {  

            List<Employee> list=new ArrayList<Employee>();  
            while(rs.next()){  
            Employee e=new Employee();  
            e.setId(rs.getInt(1));  
            e.setName(rs.getString(2));  
            e.setSalary(rs.getInt(3));  
            list.add(e);  
            }  
            return list;  
            }  
        });  
      }     
}
```

**Test.java**

```
 package com.develop;
    import java.util.List;
    import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;    
    public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ApplicationContext ctx=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");              
             EmployeeDao dao=(EmployeeDao)ctx.getBean("edao");  
                List<Employee> list=dao.getAllEmployees();                        
                for(Employee e:list)  
                    System.out.println(e);                        
                } 
    }
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">  

<bean id="ds" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
<!-- <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />  
<property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe" />  
<property name="username" value="system" />  
<property name="password" value="oracle" />  -->

<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />  
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springdatabase" />  
<property name="username" value="root" />  
<property name="password" value="admin123" />

</bean>  

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">  
<property name="dataSource" ref="ds"></property>  
</bean>  

<bean id="edao" class="com.develop.EmployeeDao">  
<property name="template" ref="jdbcTemplate"></property>  
</bean>  

</beans>
```

Created Table

**CREATE TABLE employee(id number(10),NAME varchar2(100),salary number(10));**

Comment: Which version of Spring are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message clearly sais it:

> The ResultSetExtractor is not generic.

The interface was made generic in a newer version of Spring. But anyway, you can still use it's raw form, although you'd be forced you do a cast when working with the result of the `extractData()` method.

```
public List<Employee> getAllEmployees(){  
    return template.query("select * from employee",new ResultSetExtractor(){  
        @Override  
         public Object extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException,  
            DataAccessException {  

            List<Employee> list=new ArrayList<Employee>();  
            while(rs.next()) {  
                Employee e=new Employee();  
                e.setId(rs.getInt(1));  
                e.setName(rs.getString(2));  
                e.setSalary(rs.getInt(3));  
                list.add(e);  
            }  
            return list;  
        }  
    });  
  }
```

---

P.S.:
I assume you're using an old version of the Spring Framework, because in the newer version(s), the [`ResultSetExtractor` is actually generic](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/ResultSetExtractor.html). So, you can either update your Spring version (but be careful, because this might cause you compilation problems and other issues), or stick to the approach used in the code snippet above.